# Ability to highlight (mark) portions of code

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Would like the ability to apply a highlighter (background yellow, red, etc..) to identify a specific section of code to draw attention to it. Note that this would be inside of the formatted code itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://pastebin.com does this in a very neat way!

"To highlight particular lines, prefix each line with @@"
I see it as a proper inspiration.

Pastebin is also open source:
http://pastebin.com/pastebin.tar.gz
So it is easy to see how the implementation works.

Answer (score 3):

Post minimal code fragments that have been abstracted down to *just* what it takes to exhibit the problem?

Then all the code is necessary, and highlighting is not.

/pet peeve

I know that this is not always possible, but it *is* possible much more often than people use it.

Answer (score 2):

That would require changes to the code used to do syntax-coloring right now, which isn't managed by SO. It would be a nice feature though. Perhaps for now your best bet is to show the code without its context, and with its context. It's a bit more verbose than what you're proposing, but it's the best way I can think to achieve this right now.

#### Example:

What's wrong with this:

```
echo ('Hello World);
```

From this:

```
public function introduction() {
  if (isset($foo)) {
    $bar->logConv();
    echo ('Hello World);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell it to [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/); that's what SO uses.  Of course, you can always just do something like:

> ```
> here
> is
> important stuff
> some
> code
> ```
>
> Note this section:
>
> ```
> important stuff
> ```

Comment: Or just... add comments to the code.